# I need a dynamic line with a curve in React with SVGs?

Tags: reactjs, svg

[image: Here is one example of the expected result]My Problem is that i need a React Component, where i can specify line direction and curve direction and line height.
It then should return a line like the one pasted. Being quite new to SVGs, i had difficulties drawing this line with the curve dynamically and correctly.

```
import React, { SVGProps } from "react";

type Props = SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & {
  // Add any additional props you want to expose, e.g., customColor?: string;
  length: number;
  strokeWidth: number;
};

export const PipeLine: React.FC<Props> = ({
  length,
  strokeWidth = 2,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <svg
      width={length + strokeWidth}
      height={strokeWidth * strokeWidth}
      viewBox={`0 0 ${length + strokeWidth} ${10 + strokeWidth}`}
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      {...props}
    >
      <path
        d={
          `M0 ${strokeWidth / 2}H${length - 11}` +
          `C${length - 5.47715} 1 ${length} 5.47715 ${length} 11V11`
        }
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

This was my approach, which fails obviosly. The viewbox/width and height need to match to what??. How should the path be build. Possibly also drawing the line first, then appending a path to it??

Comment: First you need to decode the starting and ending points A and Z. For the shape above I would use a Q command. In the case A = {0,0} and Z = {length, 11} you can try 
d=``M0 ${strokeWidth / 2} H${length - 11} Q${length} ${strokeWidth / 2} ${length} 11``